# How can I connect my node app to my azure sql database?

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, tedious

I've used this tutorial microsoft provides and I can connect to the database but when I get to the SELECT part of it I get this error:

```
{[RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentLogin7WithStandardLogin state]

message:'Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentLogin7WithStandardLogin state', code:'EINAVALIDSTATE'}
```

I am using the npm modulte Tedious just like the guide said but I cannot get past this issue.

This is tutorial [Link.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-nodejs-simple-windows/)

Comment: Please add the code you tried not the tutorial you followed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Tedious Issue, one of the most common factors is Windows Authentication Enabled on top of Azure SQL.

1 - Don't use the FQDN in the domain property. If it's "company.com", use "COMPANY"
2 - Capitalization seems to matter as well. use All CAPS domain names
3 - Don't use a qualified user name (i.e. "user.name@company.com") just "user.name"

The resulting Config will probably look like

```
var config = {
    "userName": "user.name",
    "password": "password",
    "server": "servername",
    "domain": "DOMAIN_NAME_CAPITALIZED_AND_NOT_FQDM",
    "options": {
        "encrypt": false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get the same issue with you if I remove my current client ip from Azure SQL inbound rules. The main problem is that your client ip is blocked by Azure SQL firewall.

Login in [Azure manage portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), click your Azure SQL database instance in the list page, click your Azure SQL  server:

[image]

In **CONFIGURE** page, you can see your current client IP in list under the “allowed ip addresses” section, click the arrow button to add your ip in firewall rules of Azure SQL Server, click save button in bottom navigation bar to save the modification.
[image]

Then you can test your code again.